# Having problems with installing AnyLogic PE on Windows 10

Tags: anylogic

I am having problem with installing the PE version on a Windows 10 machine. Even if I skip this error, several other errors pop up. Any idea how to proceed?

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems on client machines. Skipping all errors usually works, actually. In my case, they are caused by the installer trying to copy example models into a part of Windows that is locked.

Skipping still lets me use AnyLogic, just no example models.

See if you can install as an admin (right-click the installer and launch as admin)

Comment: Thank you. I tried getting admin privilege and it worked.

Comment: great @add787. Please upvote the answer if it was useful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote